# Auto calculate form with jquery on select change

Tags: jquery

I want to autocalculate the sum of cost listed in the table. With the change of select menu. So I coded:

```
$(function() {
  var cost = $('#cost').data('val');//store cost from data-val
  $('#vat').html($(cost) * 1.07);//calculate vat from $cost
  var vat=$('#vat').val();
  //select
  $('select').on('change','#trn', function() {
    var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var trn = optionSelected.val();
        $('#total').html($(cost).val+$('vat').val+$('trn').val());

  })
});
```

But the script is not working. Somehow no error show in console.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/bwpc8tfh/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope it will be helpful to you

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  var cost = $('#cost').data('val');//store cost from data-val
  $('#vat').html(parseInt(cost) * 1.07);//calculate vat from $cost  
  $('#trn').change( function() {
      var optionSelected = $(this).val();
      var vat=$('#vat').html();
      var tot=parseInt(cost)+parseInt(optionSelected)+parseInt(vat);
      $('#total').html(tot);    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-boredered">
  <tr>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th><span id="cost" data-val="1000">1,000</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VAT</td>
    <td><span id="vat"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deliver</td>
    <td>
      <select id="trn">
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td><span id="total">xxx</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Frequently (not always) when you get no errors in the console, it can mean your jquery selector is not finding the elements you expect it to find.

When you use event delegation, the 2nd parameter selects the child elements, eg:

```
$(document).on("change", "select" ...
```

in this case, your code:

```
$('select').on('change','#trn',
```

is attempting to find `#tr` as a *child* of all `select`s - it's not a child, it is the select.  Change to:

```
$("#tr").on('change', function() ...
```

or

```
$(document).on('change', '#trn', function() ...
```

---

Once you have that fixed, you will need to change

```
$('#total').html($(cost).val+$('vat').val+$('trn').val());
```

to

```
$('#total').text(cost+$('#vat').text()*1+$('#trn').val()*1);
```

(`#vat` is a span so uses `.text()` to get the value and missing `#`)

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28xdf63g/

Comment: Your fiddle is not working sir, where should I fix? VAT is not showing.

Comment: This is the problem with putting "not working" in your question - to me it was not working because the selector was wrong **as you stated** with "*With the change of select menu*" - which I've provided a fix for here.  If it's not working due to some *other* code issue, then that wasn't asked in the question.  In this case you've used `$(num)` instead of just `num` - ie `$('#vat').text(cost * 1.07);`  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fobmdkty/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var cost = $('#cost').data('val');//store cost from data-val
  $('#vat').html(cost * 1.07);//calculate vat from $cost
  var vat=$('#vat').val();
  //select

  $("#trn").change(function () {

    var optionSelectedVal = $(this).val();
    console.log(optionSelectedVal);
    var trn = optionSelectedVal;
        $('#total').html(parseInt(cost)+parseInt($('#vat').html())+parseInt(optionSelectedVal));
  console.log(parseInt(cost)+parseInt($('#vat').html())+parseInt(optionSelectedVal));
 })   

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rzonv5q/1/)